# how can i retrive parameters from EncodeURL using jsp?

Tags: jsp-tags

I have problem with URLEncoding in JSP. My problem is that I have done URL Encoding and I redirected that page to another one called `save.jsp`.

My code is:

```
String basePath=  request.getScheme()+"://" + request.getServerName() + 
          ":" +request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
String level1approval="12345X";
**encodeUrl** = response.encodeURL(basePath+"/"+"level1approval.jsp" + 
         "?user_id=+level1approval");
```

In the JSP I'm trying to get the `user_id` value but it is giving me `null`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you fail to close properly the string.

```
response.encodeURL(basePath + "/level1approval.jsp?user_id=" + level1approval);
```